# python3 - how to change date filter in pivot table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-office, xlsx

I'm trying to make a script which will change every day date in pivot table to yesterday.
Unfortunately, every time when I try this code, Excel automatically calculates date and so from 2014-05-08 makes 41766. How to avoid this issue?

When I write it to 'normal' cell it works fine. Problem is only with pivot tables...

```
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta

now = datetime.datetime.now()
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
wczoraj = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-07")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def excel():
    """"""
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    ss = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'D:\python\skrypty\test.xlsx')
    sh = ss.Worksheets("Arkusz5")

    xl.Visible = True
    time.sleep(1)

    #kolumn,
    sh.Cells(2,2).Value = wczoraj

    ss.Close(True)
    xl.Application.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    excel()
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing "07" to "%d" in strftime

Comment: Hi Ojashwi, welcome to SO! Please read up on [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before writing your next answer :)